# AsyncStorage.getItem returns undefined : React Native

Tags: reactjs, undefined, react-native

Codeflow is-

I am checking if an entry called **listobject** exists in the AsyncStorage.

1. If it doesn't exist, then, I create an object, add few attributes and set the store. I get the store to **obj** as I have to compare in the next **if** condition.
2. If the **listobject** entry already exists(2nd time), then, it directly comes to the 2nd block, and compares. (The reason I get values to obj in 1st step is because I can have a common **obj.data.isdirty** condition.

Here is my code-

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('listobject').then((obj) => {
    if(obj == undefined)
    {
        var obj1 ={};
        obj1.data ={};
        obj1.data.isdirty = true;
        console.log("obj1 = "+ JSON.stringify(obj1));
        AsyncStorage.setItem('listobject',obj1);
        obj = AsyncStorage.getItem('listobject');
        console.log("obj = "+ JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
    if(obj.data.isdirty)
    {
        obj.data.isdirty = false;
        AsyncStorage.setItem('listobject',JSON.stringify(obj));
        return AsyncStorage.getItem('listobject');
    }
}).done();
```

I have 2 questions which are the outcome of the same issue-

1. Logs. I am setting obj1 and getting the same value for obj (so that I can compare the next if condition). Why am I not able to **get** the same value that I have **set**?

> 12-03 00:27:56.281 32598-487/com.abc D/ReactNativeJS: 'obj1 = {"data":{"isdirty":true}}'
>
> 12-03 00:27:56.286 32598-487/com.abc D/ReactNativeJS: 'obj = {"_37":0,"_12":null,"_59":[]}'

2. This is the end result of the above logs. I am getting that list.data.isdirty is undefined. I guess that because the JSON format I am accessing does not exist in **obj** i.e., obj.data.isdirty doesn't exist. So, how do I overcome this?

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'list.data.isdirty');

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The obj returning is a string, so you have to apply JSON.parse to it before the second if.

Comment: I have tried that as well, its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually copied the object from one to another. It worked.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('listobject').then((obj) => {
    if(obj == undefined)
    {
        var obj1 ={};
        obj1.data ={};
        obj1.data.isdirty = true;
        console.log("obj1 = "+ JSON.stringify(obj1));
        AsyncStorage.setItem('listobject',obj1);
        obj = obj1; //THIS IS WHAT I DID!
        console.log("obj = "+ JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
    if(obj.data.isdirty)
    {
        obj.data.isdirty = false;
        AsyncStorage.setItem('listobject',JSON.stringify(obj));
        return AsyncStorage.getItem('listobject');
    }
}).done();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite following the entire question I do however see an issue with the use AsyncStorage. Going by the name, Async implies that the operations are asynchronous. So when you do getItem(key), you should either pass in a callback or use the Promise object it returns as you are doing in the first line of code.

`obj = AsyncStorage.getItem('listobject');
        console.log("obj = "+ JSON.stringify(obj));`

`obj` is going to be the Promise in this case.

Then if you check on obj for the presence of a data and isDirty child property, they will not exist on the Promise.

Comment: If I am right, should I be using obj as - obj.then(function(){code});

Comment: Yes. I used a normal object assign and it worked. Updated the question with my solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes while doing `console.log(AsyncStorage.getItem('Soomekey'))` you will be getting `undefined` as you can't directly pull values from the AsyncStorage as returns a promise so what you should be writing is

```
 const SomeFunction = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('somekey');
      console.log(value);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```