# React Native AsyncStorage Functions is not defined

Tags: react-native

I am using AsyncStorage to store data in local storage of the device. but when I am using AsyncStorage.setItem or AsyncStorage.getItem, it gives an error that

```
_reactNative.default.getItem is not a function. (In '_reactNative.default.getItem('itemName'),'_reactNative.default.getItem' is undefined)
```

I have used import AsyncStorage from "react-native";

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051216/asyncstorage-getitem-returns-undefined-react-native) helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your import statement to `import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native`

However, as the React Native [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage) for AsyncStorage suggest, you should be using [@react-native-community/async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage).